# 2D sparse input tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to use 2D sparse input with Tensorflow 2.6, a minimal example is:

```
input1=keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,64), sparse=True)
layer1=keras.layers.Dense(32)(input1)                  
output1=keras.layers.Dense(32)(layer1)
model = keras.Model(inputs = [input1],  outputs = [output1])
model.compile()
model.summary()
```

However I end up with the following error message:

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("PlaceholderWithDefault:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

What am I doing wrong ? it works if I flatten the matrix.

Comment: Hi! It seems it's a bug in Tensorflow. Please look at similar issues on their github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues?q=Failed+to+convert+object+of+type+%3Cclass+%27tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor%27%3E (they are also other issues mentoined in issues listed in this link). I think it would be more appropriate to file an issue, we will not be able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited code:**

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,), sparse=True)
    layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(input1)                  
    output1= tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(layer1)
    model =  tf.keras.Model(inputs = [input1],  outputs = [output1])
    model.compile()
    model.summary()
```

Reference:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/sparse_tensor.ipynb#scrollTo=E8za5DK8vfo7

Comment: Thanks, but this gives a 1D input not a 2D input.